# C++ dividing doesn't give the right result

Tags: c++

I'm making a dice simulator for school, and I need to calculate the percentage a certain number has been rolled, and I gave it a test run, but somehow I got this:

```
How many dice do you want to roll?
3
How many times do you want to roll the dice?
1000000
144414: 1000000 196039 %
```

This is the code for my main class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Dice.h"
#include "DiceSimulator.h"

using namespace std;

static int inputNumber(const string question);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int numberOfDice = inputNumber("How many dice do you want to roll?");

    const int times = inputNumber("How many times do you want to roll the dice?");

    DiceSimulator sim(times, numberOfDice);

    cout << sim.howManyTimesDidWeRollACertainNumber(11) 
    << ": " << times << " " 
    << ((sim.howManyTimesDidWeRollACertainNumber(11) * 100.0) / times) 
    << " %" << endl;

    return 0;
}

int inputNumber(const string question)
{
    int number = 0;
    cout << question << endl;
    cin >> number;
    return number;
}
```

This is my DiceSimulator.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DiceSimulator.h"

using namespace std;

DiceSimulator::DiceSimulator(const int times, const int numberOfDice)
{
    this->numberOfDice = numberOfDice;
    int timesRolled[6 * numberOfDice - 2];
    Dice dice[numberOfDice];

    for(int i = numberOfDice; i <= 6 * numberOfDice; i++)
    {
        timesRolled[i - numberOfDice] = 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        int roll = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < numberOfDice; j++)
        {
            roll = roll + dice[j].roll();
        }

        timesRolled[roll - numberOfDice]++;
    }

    this->timesRolled = timesRolled;
}

int DiceSimulator::howManyTimesDidWeRollACertainNumber(int number)
{
    if(number < numberOfDice || number > numberOfDice * 6)
        return 0;

    return timesRolled[number - numberOfDice];
}
```

And this is DiceSimulator.h

```
#include "Dice.h"

#ifndef _3_01_Dice_Simulator_DiceSimulator_h
#define _3_01_Dice_Simulator_DiceSimulator_h

class DiceSimulator
{
    int numberOfDice;
    int *timesRolled;
public:
    DiceSimulator(const int times, const int numberOfDice);
    int howManyTimesDidWeRollACertainNumber(int number);
};

#endif
```

You would think that 144414 divided by 1000000 multiplied by 100 is 14.4414, right? How is it possible that this gives a wrong result?

Comment: This is impossible. Only try to realise the truth: That it is not division that is broken, but it is only your own code.

Comment: @KerrekSB: *"Only try to realise the truth"*... sounds like that little kid from [Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matrix)? :P

Comment: Could it be that `sim.howManyTimesDidWeRollACertainNumber(11)` generates a different number every time you call it? perhaps you should keep the result in a variable prior to the `cout`

Comment: Strive to make your method names shorter – while preserving readability, of course. For instance, I’d suggest `occurrencesOf`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int timesRolled[6 * numberOfDice - 2];
// ...
this->timesRolled = timesRolled;
```

You can't do that. `timesRolled` is a local variable that will go out of scope at the end of the constructor. Once that happens the memory is no longer valid and accessing any pointer to that memory will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: thanks, so how should I fix that?

Comment: So we have [bashphorisms](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/misc/bashphorisms) 0, 1 and 2 here?

Comment: @SanderDeclerck You could allocate the memory using `new[]` and make sure to `delete[]` it in the destructor. Or better yet: use `std::vector` instead of arrays.

Comment: @SanderDeclerck: I'd like to add that it's not necessary to introduce this local variable at all, you can just allocate `DiceSimulator::timesRolled` right at the beginning of the constructor and then operate on this. Thereby you save having to copy the array at the end of the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the answer has been given and accepted, but I still don't like this:

```
int timesRolled[6 * numberOfDice - 2];

for(int i = numberOfDice; i <= 6 * numberOfDice; i++)
{
    timesRolled[i - numberOfDice] = 0;
}
```

So that if, for instance, numberOfDice is 1, timesRolled is an array with 4 elements, and you fill elements 0 through 5 of it. You may want to look into that later.

Comment: I know, I already changed that to timesRolled = new int[5 * numberOfDice];

Comment: @Sander That’s horrible code. Use a `std::vector` here. [Don’t use pointers](https://twitter.com/#!/klmr/status/177173159836008448) unless you have to.

Answer (score 0):

You should never take your chances on operator precedence.  Use parens.  They don't cost much.  So change the calculation for the third number as follows:

```
((sim.howManyTimesDidWeRollACertainNumber(11) * 100.0) / times)
```

If it is still wrong after that then you need to show the code for that function...obviously no one can help you further without that.

Comment: Parens cost readability. They are utterly useless in OP’s code. There *are* situations where redundant parentheses can increase readability. But if a programmer has problems with BODMAS then I suggest they go back to prescool.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't change, I also added other code to my post...

Comment: @Konrad, I don't know offhead whether `<<` or `*` has higher precedence. I believe it is `*`. So I would appreciate at least the outer parens.

Comment: @Konrad: BODMAS are not universal and those you learned back in preschool won't necessarily be the right ones, so your argument is moot.

Comment: @Konrad:  Funny how I posted saying you shouldn't take your chances with parens, and then the OP comes in and says he doesn't know the order of precedence.  Programming in up to a dozen languages at any time through the year, I, also, do not expect to memorize the long list of precedence tables for every one of them when I can much easier eliminate the question with a few parens here and there.  I choose the practical solution.  If you wish you can choose to take your chances but I hope I don't have to ever read your code and try to figure it out.

Comment: @Johannes. Yes, *those* make sense.

Comment: @Shautieh Nonsense. BODMAS is universal (one of the few things in mathematical notations which is), it’s just that a surprising number of people apparently learn it wrong.

Comment: @Ken BODMAS is *not* “a long list of precedence tables”. It’s three simple rules, which every preschooler is expected to be able to memorise.

Comment: I searched a few sites about BODMAS and was not able to find where the stream insertion operator fits in.  Therefore I don't see how it relates to this subject (which is code involving the use of the same).  In fact the C++ order of precedence list that I consulted shows a list of 18 rules.  I simply don't have time to memorize all of that, even for one language.  So I guess I'll have to continue using those unreadable parenthesese. :(

Comment: @KonradRudolph, *Most* orders of precedence are universal across *most* programming languages.  There are exceptions though, and just because you think you know it all, that doesn't mean everyone else who reads your code does.  Be explicit in your intentions and there will be no room for misinterpretation at some point in the future.

Comment: @Ken You are putting words in my mouth and attacking a straw man. I agree very much with you that precedence rules in general are complicated and even when you have memorised them, parentheses still help understanding. My point was solely concerned with those precedence rules which are covered by BODMAS; in the context of C++, those are multiplication, division, addition and subtraction. **Nothing else**. Stream operation? Didn’t mention it. In fact, in an earlier comment to jalf I explicitly agreed that those *outer* parentheses are useful.

Comment: @James Again, I’m only concerned with the operators mentioned in BODMAS, not any other operators. Read my previous comments for clarification. You tell me to “be explicit” but my whole point is that explicitness in the form of parentheses comes at a cost, which must be offset by its usefulness.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: universal? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Exceptions_to_the_standard

Comment: @Shautieh First of all, concerning the precedence of the “slash symbol” (which isn’t a mathematical symbol at all), {{citation needed}}: the paragraph has none. Second of all (concerning the first and third paragraph): so implementations get this wrong. It happens. It’s still wrong.

Comment: @Konrad You are apparently so intent on defending your insult that in the process you are admitting it was off topic.  You didn't mention stream operation?  **The OP's code did.**  My suggestion about parens was in response to that code.  So it obviously involved more than BODMAS.  If you're just talking about BODMAS you're talking about another topic.  My answer and comments were general ones about **operator precedence**.  Perhaps you wish that that topic only involved arithmetic operators so you can defend your statement that there are only 3 rules to remember but sorry it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ken I fail to see the “insult”. And my criticism of parentheses was *only* of the inner pair. My first comment didn’t explicitly say this   (I’d mistakenly thought that the mention of BODMAS was enough) but the subsequent comments made it clear. BODMAS is *still* on topic – concerning the inner parentheses. I do not “wish” that this topic involves arithmetic operations – it just does. So how is this off topic?

Comment: It is off topic because the topic is code with an insertion operator despite your attempts to make it just about arithmetic.  It is unfortunate that now that this has been demonstrated you resort to trying to revise your comment several hours after the fact.

Comment: @Ken Now you’re the one who is insulting. Look again and you will see that **as soon as somebody pointed out** a mistake in my initial comment (Johannes Schaub), I immediately acknowledged this and answered that “yes, those make sense”. I resent your false accusation of revising my comments. From the start, my comments were meant to apply to arithmetic (hence “BODMAS”). You may choose not to believe me but don’t publicly accuse me of lying without some proof.

Comment: The "proof" is in the thread. I didn't "accuse" you of anything that anyone can't judge by reading it. You said in effect I need to go back to preschool because I don't know arithmetic-when there was more than arithmetic involved (especially since my answer was a general statement about best practices and operator precedence- involving some 18 different levels in this case).  When you said parens are utterly useless in OP's code, you didn't restrict that to the inner ones.  Your attempt to revise history is not well supported by pointing back to a doubly indirect comment @ someone else.